# Load more messages in listview implementation in android

Tags: android, listview, pagination, adapter

I display first 20 records fetched from server in a listview.

I have baseadapter which is binded to listview as an adapter, and i pass records fetched from server to this baseadapter.

I set a footer item as textview attached to listview, onclicklistener of same, it fetches new 20 records from server, then i add those 20 records and pass to baseadapter.

But it reloads whole listview again, and displays all 40 records but starting from list item 1.

I want to display whole list but cursor point should be from new items added in list, as similar to "Email application" in android.

In other words, only new items should be refreshed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to call the below code when you notify your adapter.

```
listview.setSelectionFromTop();
```

It set your item from the top.

Comment: After displaying, first 20 records, on refreshing for new items, next 20 items get loaded after 20th item in list.. Yes, setSelectionFromTop(getLastPostion(), 0) done the trick for me... getLastPostion() getter method gives postion of time before "load more..." text

Answer (score 0):

Your app can keep current listview position and after updting listview you can navigate to this position through setPosition method